# Read only hard disk dual boot windows ubuntu

Tags: mount, hard-drive, windows

i have two os on my ssd, windows and ubuntu, and a secondary hard disk for data only.
Sometimes after using windows, ubuntu is not able to write on that hard disk.
I tried to mount and unmount that drive, but i was not able to mount in write mode.
The only solution that i know is to login on windows and than reboot on ubuntu to have the right permission on that drive.
Are there other solution to avoid this kind of problem permission?

Comment: Turn off "fast boot" and "hibernation" in Windows, and do a REAL shutdown when leaving Windows. Search here on AU for the steps. Also... you should NOT be writing to your Windows C: drive from Ubuntu unless you want some real Windows problems. Create a separate NTFS partition to share files between the two OS's.

Comment: Thanks, i'm trying your solution.
for the REAL shutdown, do you mean this command: " shutdown /s /f /t 0 " ?
i'm not writing on the windows partiton but on a shared secondary hard disk for data only

Comment: After turning off "fast boot" and "hibernation", I believe that a full/real shutdown is accomplished by holding down the shift key during a shutdown (and maybe even a restart)... (I'm not a Windows guy... but I believe that's correct). Good on having a separate data partition. Is it the C: drive, or the separate data drive that is giving you trouble?

Comment: Thanks for the help. The drive is an hard disk different from C labeled partiton. I have  an ssd patitioned to allow dual boot with windows and ubuntu and both of them have access to the hard disk for data storage. Sometimes after windows session i run up again this problem where ubuntu is not able to write on hard disk. Thanks for the suggests.